# Configuration checks in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

With .NET Core, reading application configuration via `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration` has changed significantly. I know that there are a couple of packages and blog posts about how to read different configuration sources: environment variables, JSON files, command line, etc. But until now, the topic of validating the configuration hasn't been covered so much - at least it didn't reach me.

Does anybody know some NuGet package (the more official the better) that allows to specify certain rules/checks based on the configuration? For example, at the moment, my application startup usually looks like this:

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)    
                 .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                 .Build();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["property1"])) throw new ArgumentNullException("property1");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["property2"])) throw new ArgumentNullException("property2");
```

Do I have to write my own extension methods for `IConfiguration` or is there already a "ready to use" package?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Options` they have the possibility to add validations rules and much more like 
to update on some changes etc..

[Option validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#options-validation)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to automate validating strongly typed configuration but for key/value  `config["property1"]` I don't think so.

[Adding validation to strongly typed configuration objects in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/adding-validation-to-strongly-typed-configuration-objects-in-asp-net-core/)

[Validating Configuration objects in ASP.NET Core](https://medium.com/cheranga/validating-configuration-objects-in-asp-net-core-e22452224537)

[Validate strongly typed options when using config sections](https://keestalkstech.com/2019/09/validate-strongly-typed-options-when-using-config-sections/)

[Using ASP.NET Core configuration mechanism with valid objects](https://antao.github.io/aspnetcore/dotnetcore/options-pattern/validation/configuration/2018/09/21/aspnetcore-configuration-mechanism/)